# How to avoid dialog box when using echo in vimrc/gvimrc file?

Tags: vimrc, startup, echo

If there is a `echo/echom` sentence in the `vimrc` or `gvimrc` file, a **dialog box** is popped out when gvim starts.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! One thought that comes to mind—is there any reason you can’t just *not* echo in your rc files? Feel free to [edit] to explain why you are in this situation

Comment: there are several situations that 'echo' is required in the rc files to log messages, one of which is vim is used as an everyday tool and is required to fetch some information from web while starting and render it in the message area.

Comment: During startup `echom` enforces a dialog. Only after the GUI is ready messages are displayed inside GVim's window. Could you store the messages in a global list variable and print them later? Something like `call add(g:mylog, 'A Message')` and `for s in g:mylog | echomsg s | endfor`.

Comment: thanks, this is a good idea. but i don't know how to envoke the print after the GUI is ready?

Comment: Based on Jürgens comment: `autocmd GUIEnter * for s in g:mylog | echomsg s | endfor`. Note: That way you only see the messages in gvim, but not in a terminal vim. You could use `if has("gui_running")` to test for gvim.

Comment: `autocmd VimEnter * ...` should work also.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)